# Javascript: How to make _.compact ignore 0 as a falsy value?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm currently extracting real time data as entered in an html table and calculating a certain value out of each column values. For this, I need to use `_.chain()` and `_.pluck`, and to scrape out the values like `null` and `undefined`, I'm using `_.compact()` like this:

```
var vals = _.chain(values).pluck(operand).compact().value();
```

But this removes values which are `0` as well. Instead, I'd like to keep the `0` values. It works fine for everything like `0.1`, etc., but not for 0.

> ```
> For this array: 
> 0: {A: 4}
> 1: {T: 6}
> 2: {A: 1}
> 3: {T: 6}
> when operand='A', vals=4,1 ==> size of vals[] = 2
> ```

But

> ```
> For this array: 
> 0: {A: 4}
> 1: {T: 6}
> 2: {A: 0}
> 3: {T: 6}
> when operand='A', vals=4 ==> size of vals[] = 1 //missing value 0
> ```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the definition of `operand`

Comment: its' nothing @David, just a variable to store a particular key in the array. Anyway, I'll update the question with sample data.

Comment: The problem might result from using `.compact()`. According to the Underscore docs, `compact` "Returns a copy of the list with all falsy values removed. In JavaScript, `false`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `undefined` and `NaN` are all falsy.". This means, if `operand` returns a primitive value which is `0`, `compact` removes it. In  that case, use `filter` with a custom function instead of `compact`

Comment: Added sample input/output @David. Sorry about that, meant to say `compact` instead of `pluck`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions depends on what `operand` extracts. If it returns `0`, the value will be removed by the subsequent call to `compact`. You can try this:

```
_.chain(values).pluck(operand).filter(x => x != null).value()
```

The `x != null` part removes any `null` and/or `undefined` values but leaves the rest untouched.

Comment: Thanks @David. This worked. As you said, the `compact` was just ignoring the values which were `0`. using `filter` solved it.

Answer (score 3):

That's not `.pluck`'s fault, but `.compact`'s:

[Docs](https://underscorejs.org/#compact):

> **compact**
>
> Returns a copy of the **list** with all falsy values removed. In JavaScript, *false, null, 0, "", undefined* and *NaN* are all falsy.

You can avoid that by using `.filter(v => !!v || v === 0)` instead of `.compact()`.

Comment: Using `!!v` means that your filtering function returns `false` for `0`. That way, `0` values will always be removed and that's not what the OP wants. Instead, he wants to _keep_ `0` values.

Comment: @David Yes, thanks, messed up this condition, it should be `|| v===0`, fixed.